# How To Search two Tables in asp.net

Tags: c#

I have this tables below

Reservation Table

```
CheckInDate datetime Unchecked
CheckOutdate datetime Unchecked
NoOfDays int Unchecked
RoomId int Unchecked
Booking_Charges float Unchecked
NoOfAdults int Checked
NoOfKids int Checked
```

room Table

```
RoomId int Unchecked
RoomType varchar(50) Unchecked
```

on my default.aspx

I have this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtCheckIn" runat="server" >

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtCheckout" runat="server" >
```

but it uses calendar control...

My Aim is to search the available rooms....as in to get the rooms that is not in reservation table at the particular date selected

How can i achieve that...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What database system etc...

Answer (score 0):

if the user selects an end date and start date (the checkin and checkout that is checked)

then your check would be in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Rooms
WHERE RoomId NOT IN (
    SELECT RoomId
    FROM Reservations
    WHERE CheckInDate <= @SelectedEndDate AND CheckOutDate >= @SelectedStartDAte
)
```